# @PushEndpoint leads to TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

Tags: primefaces, apache-tomee

I am trying to use @PushEndpoint like in the Primefaces showcase: 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.OnMessage;
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.PushEndpoint;
import org.primefaces.push.impl.JSONEncoder;

@PushEndpoint("/notify")
public class NotifyResource {

    @OnMessage(encoders = { JSONEncoder.class })
    public FacesMessage onMessage(FacesMessage message) {
        return message;
    }
}
```

As soon as I use this example, my server won't start anymore:

```
SEVERE: CDI Beans module deployment failed
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
```

The problem comes from the line

```
(encoders = { JSONEncoder.class })
```

Full stack trace: http://pastie.org/10936442

Comment: What version of TomEE and what version of Primefaces? Also can you post your `pom.xml`?

Comment: I answered my own question. Still, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem was a ClassNotFoundException**

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.atmosphere.config.managed.Encoder

And Atmosphere is not included in primefaces.jar

**Simply add the dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
    <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.atmosphere/atmosphere-runtime/2.2.6